# Python disable logging only on one logfile

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I configured the logging on the screen and on two separate logfiles, one INFO and one just ERROR.

By setting LOG INFO DISABLE = 1 I would like to be able to disable logging on the INFO logfile while maintaining logging on the ERROR file and on the screen.
My files:

logging.conf

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=screen, file1, file2

[formatters]
keys=simple,complex

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(filename)s  %(levelname)-5s %(message)s
datefmt=[%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S]

[formatter_complex]
format=%(asctime)s - [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d in function '%(funcName)s']  %(levelname)-5s %(message)s
datefmt=[%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S]

[logger_root]
handlers = screen,file1,file2
level = NOTSET

[handler_file1]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=15
formatter=simple
level=INFO
args=('info.log',)

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=simple
level=INFO
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_file2]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=15
formatter=complex
level=ERROR
args=('error.log',)
```

bot.py

```
import logging

##### LOGGING
if LOG_INFO_DISABLE == 1:
    logging.disable(logging.ERROR)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

...
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging.config
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
    ...
```

As it is now it also disables screen logging for me.

Comment: I suggest you use the handler functionality, see [docs](https://realpython.com/python-logging/#using-handlers)

Comment: disable handle output to file, but keep output to console

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to disable handler_file1 without also disabling handler_file2.
I looked at the documentation and many guides but I didn't find an example like mine. I've made many attempts but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the level for handler_file1 to WARNING, which means it will only log messages with severity WARNING or higher. INFO messages will not be logged to the file, but they will still be logged to the console.

```ini
[handler_file1]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=15
formatter=simple
level=WARNING  # Change this line to set the desired level
args=('info.log',)
```

Comment: Yes of course the constant is set in another file which I have not included for simplicity.
My problem is that when I set the constant to 1 it disables logging on logfile info.txt and also on screen.
I want to disable logging only on info.txt but continue to see logging on screen.

Comment: @AdrianoMeis see my updated  answer